# SQL amount consumed query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do you do a query to calculate how much of an item has been consumed (used up)?

We can find the qty of each item that we purchased in a purchases table with columns Id, ProductId, Qty (decimal), Date

```
Id, ProductId, Qty, Date    
1,  1,         10,  1/1/11
2,  1,         5,   2/2/11
3,  1,         8,   3/3/11
```

And how do you then add a count of how many of each row in the purchase table have been consumed - assuming strict FIFO? So in the above example if we know that 14 have been consumed the output would be:

```
Id, ProductId, Qty, Date,    Consumed    
1,  1,         10,  1/1/11,  10
2,  1,         5,   2/2/11,  4
3,  1,         8,   3/3/11,  0
```

Hopefully that explains what I mean by an amount consumed query - we know 14 were consumed and that the first purchase was for 10, so all 10 have been consumed. The next purchase was for 5 so we know that 4 of those have been consumed.

Theres two places I can get the consumed data from - the ConsumedItems table: columns Id, ProductId, QtyUsed, Date), or from the ConsumedSummaryView with columns ProductId, QtyUsed (this is the sum of ConsumedItems.QtyUsed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little different approach than Richard's, but I'm not sure which will perform better:

```
SELECT
    Purchases.Id,
    Purchases.ProductId,
    Purchases.Qty,
    Purchases.Date, 
    CASE
        WHEN COALESCE (PreviousPurchases.PreviousUsed, 0) + Qty < ConsumedSummaryView.QtyUsed THEN Qty
        ELSE
            CASE
                WHEN ConsumedSummaryView.QtyUsed - COALESCE (PreviousPurchases.PreviousUsed, 0) < 0 THEN 0 
                ELSE ConsumedSummaryView.QtyUsed - COALESCE (PreviousPurchases.PreviousUsed, 0)
            END
    END AS Used
FROM
    Purchases
    INNER JOIN ConsumedSummaryView ON Purchases.ProductId = ConsumedSummaryView.ProductId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            SUM(Purchases_2.Qty) AS PreviousUsed,
            Purchases_1.Id
        FROM
            Purchases AS Purchases_2
            INNER JOIN Purchases AS Purchases_1 ON Purchases_2.Id < Purchases_1.Id
                                               AND Purchases_2.ProductId = Purchases_1.ProductId
        GROUP BY
            Purchases_1.Id
    ) AS PreviousPurchases ON Purchases.Id = PreviousPurchases.Id
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to work? I get Used = 10, NULL, 0 for the 3 rows (using @Richard test data setup script above + plus your query)

Comment: Sorry, left a variable in there.  Try it now.

Answer (score 5):

Sample table and view

```
create table purchases (Id int, ProductId int, Qty int, Date datetime)
insert purchases select 1,  1,         10,  '1/1/11'
insert purchases select 2,  1,         5,   '2/2/11'
insert purchases select 3,  1,         8,   '3/3/11'
create view ConsumedSummaryView as select ProductID = 1, QtyUsed = 14
```

The query

```
;with p as (
    select *, rn=ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by productid order by date, id)
    from purchases)
, tmp(Id, ProductId, Qty, Date, rn, ToGo, Consumed) as (
    select p.Id, p.ProductId, p.Qty, p.Date, cast(1 as bigint),
            CAST(ISNULL(v.qtyused,0) - p.Qty as decimal(20,10)),
        cast(case
            when v.qtyused >= p.Qty Then p.Qty
            when v.qtyused > 0 then v.qtyused
            else 0 end as decimal(20,10))
    from p
    left join ConsumedSummaryView v on p.ProductId = v.productId
    where rn=1
    union all
    select p.Id, p.ProductId, p.Qty, p.Date, cast(p.rn as bigint),
            cast(ISNULL(tmp.toGo,0) - p.Qty as decimal(20,10)),
        cast(case
            when tmp.toGo >= p.Qty Then p.Qty
            when tmp.toGo > 0 then tmp.toGo
            else 0 end as decimal(20,10))
    from tmp
    --inner join p on p.rn=tmp.rn+1
    inner join p on p.rn=tmp.rn+1 and p.productid = tmp.ProductId
)
select Id, ProductId, Qty, Date, Consumed
from tmp
order by rn
```

Output

```
Id          ProductId   Qty         Date                    Consumed
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------- -----------
1           1           10          2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 10
2           1           5           2011-02-02 00:00:00.000 4
3           1           8           2011-03-03 00:00:00.000 0
```

Comment: Thanks that's very close. But I forgot to say that Qty is a decimal . Your solution has this error "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "ToGo" of recursive query "tmp""

Comment: If you change the sample table above to read `create table purchases (Id int, ProductId int, Qty decimal, Date datetime)` then you can see the error occurring

Comment: @JK When in doubt, CAST both parts of a recursive CTE - answer updated. Drop decimal from 20,10 to something more reasonable

Comment: When used on actual data I'm getting: (261448 row(s) affected) and it takes 2 minutes.  There are 138 rows in the purchases table and 117 rows in the consumed view.

Comment: @JK Are there multiple columns in `ConsumedSummaryView` per ProductId?

Comment: Doesnt appear to be - I've attached my test data to the question now

Comment: Sorry - updated the test data, insert portion was wrong for the consumed view.

Comment: @JK sorry, missed a join condition - the query has changed, the last INNER JOIN now links by productid

Comment: Yup that's it, and instant too.  Hmm, both queries work and have the same speed - who to tick?? I think its going to have to be @judah since I got his one going first.

Comment: @JK - Judah's query does appear to be faster